# Jasmine test for testing a function call failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, web, jasmine

I have the following javascript-

```
function changeSelectBoxTitle() {
  var value = $('#reason_id').find('option:selected').text();
  $('#reason_id').attr('title', value);
}

$(document).on('change', '#reason_id', function() {
  changeSelectBoxTitle();
});
```

Basically on the change of a select box the changeSelectBoxTitle() function should be called. Testing it via UI passes. I am trying to test this call through jasmine.
This is my jasmine test-

```
describe('when select box value is changed', function() {
    it('calls the changeSelectBoxTitle function', function() {
        spyOn(window, 'changeSelectBoxTitle');
        var $dropDown = $('#reason_id');
        $dropDown.change();
        expect(window.changeSelectBoxTitle).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Everything looks good. but the test fails. I have no idea why. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The code looks alright. I'd look at the more basic things like, in the test, does $dropdown actually have an element selected? There must be something else going wrong elsewhere, maybe in your setup.

Answer (score 1):

As @eck has said in the comment below your question, there is nothing wrong with your code and, the test failure is due to the test setup.

Adding the following html element to your setup will allow the test to pass

```
  <select id="reason_id" class="" name="">
    <option selected value="One">One</option>
    <option value="Two">Two</option>
  </select>
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nicholas_Murray/8tcyndmm/) where your test is passing.